# Visualise multiple disappearing pdb files in Pymol

Tags: python, pymol

I have a sequence of pdb files which I want to load in pymol window so that it gives an impression of a video. I am using cmd.load function in a loop and deleting the loaded file in the next step. But for some reason the window pauses until all iteration steps have been completed and giving nothing else in the end. I know that the files are loaded because without the “delete” line I can find all pdbs overlapped on one another. Any suggestions? Thanks and regards

```
def trial(pathname, num_files):
    for i in range(num_files):
        filename = (pathname + str(i + 1)  +'.pdb')
        print(filename)
        # print(i)
        cmd.load(filename, (i+1))
        cmd.hide()
```

Comment: https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Frame is the way —you are after moviemaking which is rich in tutorials, so I am just leaving the link here. Hopefully a tutorial about working with Frames with answer your Q.